# A proof and a question about contradiction

Tags: proof-verification, logic

Is it true that (every element is in $\mathbb{R}$)

$$\forall\epsilon >0 \left(a\leq b\epsilon\right) \Rightarrow a\leq 0 ,$$

or should it be

> $\forall b\in \mathbb{R} \left( \forall\epsilon >0 \left(a\leq b\epsilon\right) \Rightarrow a\leq 0\right)$.

Attempt at a proof of the second statement:
Let $b\in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. Assume that for all $\epsilon >0$, $a\leq b\epsilon$. We want to show that $a\leq0$. Let us assume on the contrary that $a>0$. Choose $\epsilon=a$, then $a\leq ba$, meaning $b\geq 1$. However, we assumed $b$ was arbitrary, contradiction.

My question is the following: Does assuming $b$ to be arbitrary and then showing somehow that $b$ satisfies extra conditions count as a contradiction?

If this constitutes a proof of the second statement, I can't see the first one being correct if the universal quantifier is missing.

Comment: I'd even say that $\forall a\in\Bbb R(\forall b\in\Bbb R(\forall \epsilon>0(a\le b\epsilon)\to a\le 0))$

Comment: Yes, it counts as a contradiction as the statement is true for every $b\in\mathbb{R}$ and you showed that it is only true for $b\geq1$. Also, I agree with Hagen von Eitzen's comment.

Comment: By the way, none of your statements $\forall\epsilon >0 \left(a\leq b\epsilon\right) \Rightarrow a\leq 0$ and $\forall b\in \mathbb{R} \left( \forall\epsilon >0 \left(a\leq b\epsilon\right) \Rightarrow a\leq 0\right)$ make sense because you have at least 1 variable free. Only the statement in Hagen's comment make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The proof you presented, in its most direct interpretation, shows
$$ (a>0\land\forall\epsilon>0(a\le \epsilon b))\implies b\ge 1. $$
By throwing in some contraposition, this becomes
$$ b<1\implies (\forall \epsilon>0(a\le\epsilon b)\implies a\le 0)$$
For the still free variables $a,b$, we add quantors (which one might argue were  implicitly there all the time)
$$\forall a\in\Bbb R( \forall b<1 (\forall \epsilon>0(a\le\epsilon b)\implies a\le 0)).$$
This is logically  weaker than
$$\forall a\in\Bbb R( \forall b\in \Bbb R (\forall \epsilon>0(a\le\epsilon b)\implies a\le 0)).$$

Comment: So, to assume $b\in \mathbb{R}$ and to arrive at $b\geq 1$ constitutes a contradiction or not? Because, the way I see it $b\in \mathbb{R}$ would mean that $b=1$ or $b>1$ or $b<1$. An if this is true then any of the three "or's" could be true, and I do not see a contradiction. Which confuses me as @yanko claimed in his answer before that it does constitute a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider two cases, $b \leq 0$ and $ b > 0$. The first case is obvious. For the second case (as in your proof, assume $a > 0$), choose $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon < a/b$, this implies $$a \leq b\epsilon < b.\frac{a}{b}  = a$$ which a contradiction.